# Database design normalized or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I have the following tables

```
Groups
- Id
- Name

People
- Id
- GroupId
- EntryDate (DateTime)
```

Now I want to retrieve all groups sorted by group's People entrydate that's the latest.

```
//pseudo code

select * from groups order by (select top 1 from people order by entrydate desc)
```

Would it be better to add a LatestEntryDate field to Groups and update that when a person is added? since this will be a common query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT g.Id, g.Name, MAX(p.EntryDate) AS LatestPeopleEntryDate
FROM Groups g
    INNER JOIN People p
        ON p.GroupId = g.Id
GROUP BY g.Id, g.Name
ORDER BY MAX(p.EntryDate)
```

No, I wouldn't add a `LatestEntryDate` field to the `Groups` table.  This is easily calculated.

As @danihp pointed out, you may want to use a left join here.  The above query will require that a value exists in the `People` table.  What you choose to use depends on your specific requirements.

```
SELECT g.Id, g.Name, MAX(p.EntryDate) AS LatestPeopleEntryDate
FROM Groups g
    LEFT JOIN People p
        ON p.GroupId = g.Id
GROUP BY g.Id, g.Name
ORDER BY MAX(p.EntryDate)
```

**UPDATE**

To answer your question about doing this in Linq, I think it would be something like this:

```
var result = groups.Select(g => 
    new {
            g.Id, 
            g.Name, 
            LatestPeopleEntryDate = g.People.Max(p => p.EntryDate)
        });
```

Comment: Requeriments are 'all groups':  "Now I want to retrieve **all groups** sorted by group with the latest People entrydate." Now is right +1

Comment: I think it should be 'order by LatestPeopleEntryDate desc' right?

Comment: Since your question said "sorted by group" I sorted the query by the group name.  If you wanted to sort by the date, you could use `ORDER BY MAX(p.EntryDate)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a test example with very small sample data that shows three approaches.

To get the best query plan:

Put an non-unique index on People by (GroupID, EntryDate.)

A.  Use the original pseudo-code (which does the order by but doesn't show date) or

B.  Use a top 1 subquery to get and show the date.

The query plans for A and B are the same.

Using a left join to the People table and a max() will cause scanning (within the GroupID, at best) to get the maximum, rather than a probe to the single row in the index.

```
set nocount on
if object_id('Groups') is not null drop table Groups
if object_id('People') is not null drop table People
go

-- set up tables
create table Groups
(
    ID int primary key,
    Name varchar(20)
)

create table People 
(
    ID int,
    GroupID int,
    EntryDate datetime
)
-- make an index that is ordered by Group, EntryDate
create index IE_GroupDate on People(GroupID, EntryDate)

-- Sample data
insert into Groups (ID, Name)
values
    (1, 'Group1'),
    (2, 'Group2'),
    (3, 'GroupC')

insert into People (ID, GroupID, EntryDate)
values 
    (1, 1, '2012-01-01'),
    (2, 1, '2012-02-01'),
    (1, 3, '2007-12-31')

-- Queries
-- Equivalent to the original poster's intent.  Note that it doesn't actually
-- show the entry date
select *
from Groups G
order by (
    select top 1 EntryDate
    from People P
    where P.GroupID = G.ID order by EntryDate desc)

-- Same query (by query plan) but includes the EntryDate in the result set
select
    G.ID,
    G.Name,
    LatestEntryDate = Latest.EntryDate
from Groups G
outer apply (
    select top 1 EntryDate
    from People P
    where P.GroupID = G.ID
    order by EntryDate desc
) Latest
order by LatestEntryDate

-- Query using left join.  This causes a scan of the left join table to
-- compute the max.  (The optimizer isn't smart enough to turn this into 
-- a TOP 1)
select
    G.ID,
    G.Name,
    LatestEntryDate = max(P.EntryDate)
from Groups G
left join People P on P.GroupID = G.ID
group by G.ID, G.Name
order by max(P.EntryDate)
```